# C++ dynamic allocation in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, dynamic-allocation

I made a pointer variable, ptr_view, in a main cpp for dynamic allocation
to create some views & buttons in the screen.

And sch, this is a common pointer in class_A, class_B ... 
for indicating main class to access that pointer ptr_view.
When the button class_A made get pressed, the function like below is running.

```
void class_A::ChangeView_B()
{
CC_SAFE_DELETE(sch->ptr_view);
sch->ptr_view = new  class_B;
sch->ptr_view->RCreation(main_view);
}
```

but this obviously creates an error, I finally got to know why,
since the memory of class_A is terminated when CC_SAFE_DELETE is running
so 'sch' is no more exist when trying to access sch->ptr_view.
But still don't know how to fix this problem.
Does anyone can give me little clue to get through this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic would be much easier to reason about if you used a smart pointer type for managing your memory. Cocos2d-x provides its own smart pointer type, `cocos2d::RefPtr<T>`, which is essentially a reference-counted pointer (think `std::shared_ptr<T>` or Objective-C ARC).

That said, given the information in the question, there is no reason the code you posted shouldn't work. `CC_SAFE_DELETE(sch->ptr_view)` (which is effectively `delete ptr; ptr = nullptr;`) shouldn't delete `sch`. There may be other memory bugs in your program. Again: smart pointers are your friend.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! But when i delete the code CC_SAFE_DELETE(sch->ptr_view) and insert a new function like cleanUp(), which deletes all buttons and resources that class_A left in the scene, no errors were occuring. I also had debugging this and found delete ptr->view creates the error.. After this code, "sch" returns null. Do you have other ideas that can resolve only in C++? I don't know about Objective-C at all.

Comment: I solved this problem very simply. I just moved the "ptr_view" to other singleton class so I don't need to make such variable like "sch" in every class... But thanks a lot logan20735, I got to know about what the smart pointer is.